# Having trouble with a Group By in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by

Here's my LINQ query:

```
var results = from l in leads
   from qr in l.QuoteRevisions
   from rp in qr.RevisionProducts
   select new QuoteSearchItem
   {
       ID = l.ID,
       ....
       ProductCodes = l.QuoteRevisions.SelectMany(qr => qr.RevisionProducts)
            .Select(p => p.Product.ProductCode).ToList()
   };
```

The object we are trying to fill up looks like this:

```
public class QuoteSearchItem
{
    public LeadID {get; set; }
    ....
    public List<string> ProductCodes { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

The results I'm getting are *almost* accurate.  But the problem is, when there is more than one product code, I get identical rows for each lead.  So in stead of getting this:

```
{"LeadID": "12", "ProductCodes": ["Code1", Code2"]}
```

I get this:

```
{"LeadID": "12", "ProductCodes": ["Code1", Code2"]}
{"LeadID": "12", "ProductCodes": ["Code1", Code2"]}
```

So, I need to Group By l.LeadID.  But I'm having trouble with that syntax.  I tried this:

```
var results = from l in leads
   from qr in l.QuoteRevisions
   from rp in qr.RevisionProducts
   group l by l.ID into lds
   select new QuoteSearchItem
   {
       ID = lds.ID,
       ....
       ProductCodes = lds.QuoteRevisions.SelectMany(qr => qr.RevisionProducts)
            .Select(p => p.Product.ProductCode).ToList()
   };
```

But then "lds" doesn't seen to contain anything. Not sure how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting all revision products and then constructing a list of leads. That is the problem, because now for every revision product you get one element containing all revision products for its lead.

Try removing subsequent `from`:

```
var results = from l in leads
    select new QuoteSearchItem
    {
        ID = l.ID,
        ....
        ProductCodes =
            l.QuoteRevisions
                .SelectMany(qr => qr.RevisionProducts)
                .Select(p => p.Product.ProductCode)
                .ToList()
    };
```